# ASP.NET MVC page redirect to IS4's login straight away without going to home page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm trying to learn IS4 at the moment, there's 3 projects in my solution: API, .NET MVC and IS4. My problem is when I starts the project, it redirect to IS4's login page, without going to the home page of the application. What did I do wrong?

I set the solution to start API, IS4, MVC - in that order:
[image]

And when the MVC project starts, I believe I set it to start at the home page:
[image]

And this is my controller's Index action:

```
[Authorize]
public class GalleryController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        //await WriteOutIdentityInformation();

        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("APIClient");

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(
            HttpMethod.Get,
            "/api/images/");
        
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(
            request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {   
            return View(new GalleryIndexViewModel(
                await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Image>>(responseStream)));
        }             
    }
}
```

How/why did it redirect straight away to IdentityServer's login page, skipping the Index page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong.  The `[Authorize]` attribute on your home page's controller will cause a redirect to IS to authenticate the user.

Comment: Furthermore, if you don't want to every action in a controller to require authentication, you can remove the attribute from the controller class level to each Action that you wish to have authentication instead.